# Order of a given element in an abelian group.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

**Question.** Let $G$ be an abelian group and $f,g\in G$. Suppose the order of $f$ is $3$ and the order of $g$ is $2$.

What is the order of $fg$?

**Attempt.** We need to find a non-negative integer $x$ such that $(fg)^x=1$. Since the order of $f$ is $3$ we have $f^3=1$, or equivalently $f^6=1$. Similarly, $g^2=1$ gives $g^6=1$. So: $x$ must equal $6$.

Is this correct? If so, is the answer concrete enough? If not, where have I gone wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems correct to me since the group is abelian. The order of the product of two elements in abelian group is the least common multiple of the orders of elements unless they are not inverses of each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need slightly more detail.  $(fg)^x=1$ does not always imply $f^x=1$.  It does in this case because $(fg)^x=1$ implies $f^x=(g^x)^{-1}$, and powers of $f$ have order dividing $3$ whilst powers of $g$ have order dividing $2$, and the only number dividing both $2$ and $3$ is $1$, so $f^x$ has order 1, i.e., $f^x=1$ and similarly for $g$.  Now you just check that the smallest positive $x$ with $f^x=g^x=1$ is $6$ since $6$ is the least common multiple of $2$ and $3$.

To see why your argument doesn't work in general, consider $G$ the group of rotations about an axis.  $G$ is abelian, and is $f$ is counterclockwise rotation by $45$ degrees and $g$ is counterclockwise rotation by $135$ degrees, then $f$ and $g$ each have order $8$, but $fg$ has order $2$

Comment: Or you can just consider $f=1$ and $g=3$ in the group of integers mod $8$.

Answer (score 1):

That's good, except your haven't stated why the order of $fg$ is $6$, as opposed to say, given $f^{12} = 1$, and $g^{12} = 1$, so that $12$ is the order of $12$.  Of course, $|fg| = 6$, because it is the ***least common multiple*** of $2$ and $3$.

So, it is better to say that "we need to find ***the least*** non-negative integer $x$ such that $(fg)^x=1,$ given that $f^3 =1,$ and $g^2 = 1$.  And indeed, $x=6$ is the least possible $x$ such that $(fg)^x = 1$.

---

An example that might be helpful to consider would be the group $\mathbb Z_12$ under addition modulo $12$. It's a cyclic group, and hence it is abelian. Now, for example, the element $4$ has order 3, because $3(4) = 12 = 0\pmod {12}.$  The element 6 has order 2, since $2(6) = 12 = 0\pmod{12}$.

So what can we say about the order of element $10 = 4+6$?  It has the order of $\operatorname{lcm}(3, 2) = 6$. Indeed, $10^6 = 6(10)$ (given the group operation is additive,) and $6(10) = 60 = 0 \pmod {12}$, and there is no lesser positive integer n, such that $n(10) = 0\pmod {12}$.